# rdd from another rdd and dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an rdd similar to following:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('C3', ['P8', 'P3', 'P2']), ('C1', ['P1', 'P5', 'P5', 'P2']), ('C4', ['P3', 'P4']), ('C2', ['P3']), ('C5', ['P3', 'P9'])])
```

I have a datframe similar to following:

```
new_df = spark.createDataFrame([
("P1", "Shirt", "Green", 25, 2000),
("P2", "Jeans", "yello", 30, 1500),
("P3", "Sweater", "Red", 35, 1000),
("P4", "Kurta", "Black", 28, 950),
("P5", "Saree", "Green", 25, 1500),
("P8", "Shirt", "Black", 32, 2500),
("P9", "Sweater", "Red", 30, 1000)
], ["Product", "Item", "Color", "Size", "Price"])
```

I need to create an rdd from rdd1, where the list of values should replace with the details from dataframe, for example, P8 information should get replaced from new_df dataframe. I am expecting an output rdd similar to following:

```
[('C3', [{'Price': '2500', 'Color ': 'Black', 'Size': '32', 'Item': 'Shirt'}, {'Price': '1000', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Item': 'Sweater'}, {'Price': '1500', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Item': 'Jeans'}]), ('C1', [{'Price': '2000', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Item': 'Shirt'}, {'Price': '1500', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Item': 'Saree'}, {'Price': '1500', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Item': 'Saree'}, {'Price': '1500', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Item': 'Jeans'}]), ('C4', [{'Price': '1000', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Item': 'Sweater'}, {'Price': '950', 'Color ': 'Black', 'Size': '28', 'Item': 'Kurta'}]), ('C2', [{'Price': '1000', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Item': 'Sweater'}]), ('C5', [{'Price': '1000', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Item': 'Sweater'}, {'Price': '1000', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '30', 'Item': 'Sweater'}])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your `rdd1` to *dataframe* as well. Then you need to `explode` the *array of product* in the created *dataframe* so that you can `join` the two *dataframes* with common `Product` column. Then you can convert the joined columns of `new_df` to *json* and *select* only the necessary columns. Final step would be to *group* as in the original `rdd1` and *collect* the json strings.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, ['id', 'Product'])\
    .withColumn('Product', F.explode(F.col('Product')))\
    .join(new_df, ['Product'], 'left')\
    .select('id', F.to_json(F.struct(F.col('Price'), F.col('Color'), F.col('Size'), F.col('Item'))).alias('json'))\
    .groupBy('id')\
    .agg(F.collect_list('json'))
```

which should give you output `dataframe` as

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |collect_list(json)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C3 |[{"Price":1500,"Color":"yello","Size":30,"Item":"Jeans"}, {"Price":2500,"Color":"Black","Size":32,"Item":"Shirt"}, {"Price":1000,"Color":"Red","Size":35,"Item":"Sweater"}]                                                         |
|C4 |[{"Price":1000,"Color":"Red","Size":35,"Item":"Sweater"}, {"Price":950,"Color":"Black","Size":28,"Item":"Kurta"}]                                                                                                                   |
|C5 |[{"Price":1000,"Color":"Red","Size":35,"Item":"Sweater"}, {"Price":1000,"Color":"Red","Size":30,"Item":"Sweater"}]                                                                                                                  |
|C1 |[{"Price":1500,"Color":"yello","Size":30,"Item":"Jeans"}, {"Price":2000,"Color":"Green","Size":25,"Item":"Shirt"}, {"Price":1500,"Color":"Green","Size":25,"Item":"Saree"}, {"Price":1500,"Color":"Green","Size":25,"Item":"Saree"}]|
|C2 |[{"Price":1000,"Color":"Red","Size":35,"Item":"Sweater"}]                                                                                                                                                                           |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Changing the above `dataframe` to `rdd` is just calling `.rdd` api

**Updated**

From the comment below

> > The expected dataframe should look like: |C3 |[Map(Item -> Shirt, Price -> 2500, Size -> 32, Color -> Black), Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 35, Color -> Red), Map(Item -> Jeans, Price -> 1500, Size -> 30, Color -> Yellow)] Then only I can convert it to rdd properly

It seems that you are seeking a `MapType` and not a `StringType` in the *collected list*. For that you would have to write a `udf` function

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def mapFunction(y):
    print y
    newMap = {}
    for key, value in zip(columns, y):
        newMap.update({key: value})
    return newMap

udfFunction = F.udf(mapFunction, T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))
```

and call it within the code instead of `to_json` and `struct` functions

```
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, ['id', 'Product']) \
    .withColumn('Product', F.explode(F.col('Product'))) \
    .join(new_df, ['Product'], 'left') \
    .select('id', udfFunction(F.array([F.col(x) for x in columns])).alias('json')) \
    .groupBy('id') \
    .agg(F.collect_list('json'))
dataframe.show(truncate=False)
```

You should get output as

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |collect_list(json)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C3 |[Map(Item -> Jeans, Price -> 1500, Size -> 30, Color -> yello), Map(Item -> Shirt, Price -> 2500, Size -> 32, Color -> Black), Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 35, Color -> Red)]                                                               |
|C4 |[Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 35, Color -> Red), Map(Item -> Kurta, Price -> 950, Size -> 28, Color -> Black)]                                                                                                                               |
|C5 |[Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 35, Color -> Red), Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 30, Color -> Red)]                                                                                                                              |
|C1 |[Map(Item -> Jeans, Price -> 1500, Size -> 30, Color -> yello), Map(Item -> Shirt, Price -> 2000, Size -> 25, Color -> Green), Map(Item -> Saree, Price -> 1500, Size -> 25, Color -> Green), Map(Item -> Saree, Price -> 1500, Size -> 25, Color -> Green)]|
|C2 |[Map(Item -> Sweater, Price -> 1000, Size -> 35, Color -> Red)]                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```